# Conditional probabilities: Divisors

Tags: combinatorics

Another question on conditioned probabilities which I found interesting: A person guesses a 3 digit number and it is obvious that this number can be divided by 4. With which probability can it also be divided by 6?

Answer (score 2):

The range of $3$-digit numbers, from $100$ to $999$, contains $900$ consecutive numbers, which number is divisible by $12$. The range can therefore be paritioned into $900/12=75$ sets of $12$ consecutive numbers $\{100,101,102,103,\ldots,111\},\{112,\ldots,123\}\ldots,\{988,\ldots,999\}$. Within each such interval there are two numbers divisible by $6$ (the third and ninth each time), and $3$ divisible by $4$ (the first, fifth, and ninth), of which one is also divisible by $6$. Knowing such a number is divisible by $4$ therefore gives a probability $1/3$ that it is also divisible by $6$ (and therefore by $12$).

Comment: +1. The same reasoning shows that "to be divisible by $nm$ knowing that one is divisible by $n$" has probability $1/m$ for three digits integers, as long as $nm$ divides $900=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2$ (the present case being $n=4$, $m=3$).

Comment: @Did: Yes, the Chines remainder theorem shows that the probabilities of being divisible by two relatively prime moduli is independent as long as one is considering a range composed of an integral number of periods. I did want to stress that final condition though. Also note that there can be surprises for things that look like divisibility but aren't: I think I recall once having seen computed that the probabilities, for a random day, of being a Friday and being the 13th of a month are _not_ independent over a $28$ year period.